# GoogleTest: EXPECT_THROW catches different type?

Tags: c++, testing, googletest, throw

I'm trying to test EXPECT_THROW, like below.

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
int Foo(int a, int b){
    if (a == 0 || b == 0){
        throw "don't do that";
    }
    int c = a % b;
    if (c == 0)
        return b;
    return Foo(b, c);
}
TEST(FooTest, Throw2){
    EXPECT_THROW(Foo(0,0), char*);
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc,argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

I expect that the 'Throw2' should succeed. But it gives this error information:

```
Expected: Foo(0,0) throws an exception of type char*.
Actual: it throws a different type.
```

So what is type being thrown here?

Comment: Throwing `std::runtime_error("don't do that")` is more canonical, with `EXPECT_THROW(Foo(0,0), std::runtime_error)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"don't do that"` is a string literal, the type of which is `const char[14]`. As such it can only decay to a `const  char*`, not a `char*` like you expect.

So amending your test to `EXPECT_THROW(Foo(0,0), const char*);` should make it pass.

As an aside, I wouldn't throw an exception in this case. It'd be better IMO to simply return `std::optional` (or `boost::optional` if C++17 is not available). Getting bad inputs is not something I'd deem exceptional enough to warrant an exception.

And if I had to throw an exception, then throwing a standard exception type is loads better than a string literal. In this case `std::domain_error` seems appropriate.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181142/discussion-on-answer-by-storyteller-googletest-expect-throw-catches-different-t).

Comment: Moving comments to chat is pretty useless if the chat is not available later.